# Setting Up No-Ip on a Ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, dyndns

I have used a wget to get the latest versions from the no-ip.com site. I then had to type in my account details which went fine. I try to type in the address in a url outside my home and that url gives me nothing.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details to get this question answered.  What is your dns hostname, and what ip is it set to.  Are you behind a NAT router, or does your computer have a public IP.  If NAT is involved, is there a port forward?  Is the update client getting your internal NAT address is: 192.168.1..., or is it getting your genuine internet IP?  Has the DNS record even been updated at all by the client?

Comment: [link](http://support.no-ip.com/customer/portal/articles/375955-basic-troubleshooting-guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the (sudo apt-get install no-ip) or (sudo apt-get install noip2) does not work in the newer Ubuntu OS. You will need to (sudo apt-get install ddclient) and configure the connection inside of that.